# Failed to resolve Android Giphy SDK dependency

Tags: android, dependencies, giphy, giphy-api

I am trying to add Giphy Android SDK in my Android Project. On [Giphy SDK's documentation](https://github.com/Giphy/giphy-android-sdk-core), it is mentioned that in your Project gradle.build file, add:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url  "https://giphy.bintray.com/giphy-sdk"
    }
}
```

and in your module's gradle.build file add:

```
compile('com.giphy.sdk:core:1.0.0@aar') {
    transitive=true
}
```

But when i am Syncing it, Android Studio is giving me an error saying:

```
Failed to resolve: com.giphy.sdk:core:1.0.0
```

Does anyone have any idea what am i missing?

Comment: did you find any solution regarding this?

If yes kindly share your answer with us.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to add the following line

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url  "https://giphy.bintray.com/giphy-sdk"
    }
}
```

under `allprojects` and not under `buildscript` like so

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://giphy.bintray.com/giphy-sdk"
        }
    }
}
```